SMTP sending email to Hotmail account via PHPmailer 6.9.1
Trying to get my script below to send email to my hotmail account unsuccessfully. Tried the following email servers for Hotmail but no joy. Currently using I believe the latest version of PHPmailer 6.9.1.
smtp-mail.outlook.com PORT 587

smtp.live.com PORT 587

Telnetted the above email servers not getting connection on port 587. The commentary I read on stackoverflow regarding this goes back 10 years or more. I was able to complete this task 10 years ago myself. The php code I am using is as follows:
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"; // Enter your host here
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Username = "xxxx@hotmail.com"; // Enter your email here
$mail->Password = "xxxxxx"; //Enter your password here
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->AuthType = "OAuth2";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->From = "xxxxxx@hotmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "xxxxxx";
$mail->Sender = $fromserver; // indicates ReturnPath header
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AddAddress($email_to);
$mail->send();

Maybe it not possible to do this anymore. I was having trouble with my hotmail account on my iPhone very recently. I couldn't receive emails. When I was setting up my hotmail account on my iPhone years ago I was dealing with inbound and outbound servers and configuring them manually on my iPhone. I had to install my hotmail account afresh on my iPhone it was a two click operation  enter email and password and the rest was done automatically. No interaction with servers of any kind. It would appear the servers above the ports are blocked. How do the modern email clients send and receive email to one another now? Is it possible in 2024 to send email to email server for Hotmail account. Maybe there are other servers that might allow this.
Any advice or suggestions or directions much appreciated.

See this link and open the SMTP settings.  Hotmail doesn't officially exist any more - everything is Outlook now.

What actual error are you getting? "unsuccessfully" isn't an error message or problem description. Note that you need to ensure you're using the right authentication method and the right type of password these days. No doubt more details are in the MS documentation, and in forums such as https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/request-for-smtp-authentication-enablement/170fd820-26cd-4972-9ebb-7c7b459158e6

The errors I am getting as such is Authentication failed SMTP Connect(); failed. Yes stdunbar I setup my iPhone email account recently it was outlook.com I used with my hotmail email and  old hotmail password, once submitted all installed perfectly and worked perfectly. No interaction with servers as I had to do in the past with email on my iPhone. ADyson you talk about password type expand on that password type meaning. Yes I was experimenting with authentication as a &mail parameter omitted from the above code. I was using XOAUTH2 as an authentication parameter. No Joy though.

Yes after further research I believe its the OAuth2 Authentication is the problem I have. Not sure how to implement it though for outlook via phpmailer. Thanks folks again for pointing me in the right direction.

By password type I meant App Password. As per the link I gave you, if your outlook/Hotmail account uses 2-factor authentication normally then you'd need to set up an App Password to log in from a script

Regarding oauth, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth to start with. And then I would look at the phpmailer code samples on their guthub and see if any of them deals with that kind of scenario

I suggest reading through this issue. You have selected OAuth authentication, but you’re not doing any of the things it requires. Separately, from that thread you’ll gather that MS OAuth is extremely tricky, so base your code on this example provided with PHPMailer.

Thanks all for the above. Yes apparently Oauth is very tricky and difficult. Another approach I read is using an app password and submitting this password with your email address. this I have read can bypass the whole issue of Oauth.  The problem is my attempt to connect to the smtp-mail.outlook.com server is its not authenticating. That lead me on as to where and how to you allow your outlook email to authenticate an smtp request. I suspect this is a backend microsoft account configuration or outlook.com configuration option. I have searched both web sites to no avail. I am stuck.

The link I shared earlier describes how to set an app password

Thanks ever so much ADyson. Yes setup app password and submitted, no joy. Basic authentication disabled in my outlook (hotmail) account apparently you can't enable authentication in personal account. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/can-i-send-smtp-email-through-a-regular-outlookcom/88005d39-bb85-4e06-822a-087d0f582831 Not sure this is possible tried hard now for a week.

This is a very interesting article a must read. Microsoft and Basic Authentication Personal outlook accounts. Apparently conventional password logins via smtp including app passwords wont work any more as and from 1st October 2022. They say OAthu 2 authentication will be available though. https://forum.emclient.com/t/microsoft-and-basic-authentication-personal-outlook-accounts/94922

I'd like to thank all above for their help and assistance in this matter. It looks like the only possible way forward 2024 with Outlook email account smtp access is exploring OAuth 2 authentication. Thanks again Synchro for app password direction I saw on another stackoverflow post
